# Json path - how to get "id" only from the part with "requests" and given "title":"subject_2" parameter?

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

I have a response:

{"myRequests":[],

"requests":[

{"id":"4919fe948-f4bb-4863","profileId":1,"comments":"","title":"subject_1" ...(bla-bla-bla)...,"name":"Perf_1"},

{"id":"**7295814a1-d1e7-440d**","profileId":1,"comments":"","title":"subject_2" ...(bla-bla-bla)...,"name":"Perf_1"},

{"id":"0b548e6c2-ec40-4875","profileId":1,"comments":"","title":"subject_1" ...(bla-bla-bla)...,"name":"Perf_1"},

{"id":"**39c603faf-e3f7-4666**","profileId":1,"comments":"","title":"subject_2" ...(bla-bla-bla)...,"name":"Perf_1"},

"approvedRequests":[

{"id":"83b8f6a65-da90-4b98","comments":"accept_1", ...(bla-bla-bla)...,"name":"Perf_1"},

{"id":"4db544fd1-60fe-4b72","comments":"accept_1", ...(bla-bla-bla)...,"name":"Perf_1"},

{"id":"24705ef9f-7c5c-4d43","comments":"accept_1", ...(bla-bla-bla)...,"name":"Perf_1"},

{"id":"9d5238283-3da9-4d7d","comments":"accept_1", ...(bla-bla-bla)...,"name":"Perf_1"},
]}

---

I try to use

$.requests[?(@.comments=="")].id[0]

$.requests[?(@.comments=="" && @.title=="subject_2")].id[0]

but don't see effect - what I'm missing?

What should be correct json path in this case, to have "id" only from the part with "requests" and given "title":"subject_2" parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to go for [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) and slightly amend your query to use [pipe operator](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#pipes) like:

```
requests[? comments==''].id | [0]
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)